# Stop Ansible playbook if docker install with amazon-linux-extras does not succeed

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ansible

> **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the ansible playbook will fail if the "`Install docker`" task below does not succeed?**

Currently, the playbook reports "`changed`" as the result of the "`Install docker`" task below, and thus the playbook continues into subsequent tasks whether or not the installation of docker has been successful.

```
---
- name: Install some stuff.
  hosts: firstgroup, secondgroup
  remote_user: someuser
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root

  tasks:  

     - name: Install docker 
       command: amazon-linux-extras install -y docker
```

As you can see, this is running in Amazon Linux 2, and the installation is being done using `amazon-linux-extras`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code:

```
---
- name: Install some stuff.
  hosts: firstgroup, secondgroup
  remote_user: someuser
  become: yes

  tasks:  

     - name: Install docker 
       command: amazon-linux-extras install -y docker
       register: result
       failed_when: result.rc != 0
```

you can add register option and get return code for that command. if its zero, then it will proceed else it will fail.
other thing about user, just put "become: yes" will be sufficient to run as root

Answer (score 0):

The `command` module will always get executed. That's because it's an extremely hard (if not impossible) problem to determine whether an arbitrary command needs to be executed or not if it has been run before.

What you can do is process the output of the command to determine whether the app was installed or not. This can be done using [registers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables).

Comment: The OP asks what specific code to change in the OP.  For reference for everyone else who finds this by the search engines over time and decides whether or not to +1 an answer.